# LVM2 Included During Install What Now?

Tags: partitioning, backup

I'm running Chatet OS (xubuntu). I included LVM2 during install. When looking in GParted I can see the following:

`/dev/sbd1    ext2       /boot`

`/dev/sbd2    extended`

`/dev/sbd5    lvm2 pv    chaletos-user-vg`

My question is do I need to take snapshots manually to backup my system? Or does that LVM2 partition do everything automatically?

If I need to take snapshots, is there a VERY easy way for me to set this up to automatically take daily snapshots?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Calet OS is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly have to manually create an LVM snapshot if you want one ( using `lvcreate -s` ).  They also are only suitable for short lived use; you can't keep creating one every day and retaining them for the long haul as a means of recovering old data, which is also not at all the same thing as a backup.

If you want a backup, then you need to use a backup utility and store the backup on offline media.